# Strange creatures crawl out of the house's fireplace and attack the inhabitants

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Approximately 30 years ago, I watched a horror movie which I have been trying to identify for years. The problem is that after so many years I don't remember a lot about the movie and the only things I remember are blurred by time.

Here are the details that I do remember:

- The movie was about a group of people staying in a house (I think they were a group of friends who gathered in the house, but this I cannot confirm).
- There are some strange creatures (I remember them as a kind of small big-headed humanoids) which crawl out of the house's fireplace and attack the house inhabitants; in fact, I seem to remember that the creatures will wait for some person to be isolated from the others and then they will capture this person and drag him/her back to the fireplace, and kill him/her.

Does anyone know what movie this is?

Comment: Could it be Critters or Trolls?  They both featured small creatures, just like Gremlins, and didn't have much gore.

Comment: *Gremlins* was 1984, *Critters* and *Troll* were both released in 1986.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are talking about [Don't Be Afraid of the Dark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069992/), but this just has a couple moving into a house - not exactly a group of friends.

However, the fireplace and the big headed creatures remind me of this. [Here](http://youtu.be/4TpWSNT5QhE) is the trailer in which the trolls turn up in the end:

Comment: A remake with a Guillermo del Toro screenplay and starring Katie Holmes and Guy Pierce came out just a couple of months ago. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270761/

Comment: That's correct. The original wasn't scary at all. Wonder how the new one is

Comment: @Lelouch Lamperouge it's ok

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge: yes; this is the film. Now that I've seen it once again, I know why I thought about the group of people: the party scene fixed in my mind 30 years ago, so I (erroneously) thought about a group of friends instead of just a couple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the 1973 made for television movie [*Don't Be Afraid of the Dark*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_%281973_film%29). A couple move into an old house that she inherited. In the basement is a fireplace that has a metal door bolted over it. When she removes it, she freed the creatures locked inside. They came after her in the shower, but when she turned on the light, they fled. But they do come back. Won't spoil it any more than that.

A trailer can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TpWSNT5QhE) and here is a [blog post](http://stefanpoag.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/dont-be-afraid-of-the-dark-2011-and-1973/) describing the movie and the 2011 remake, including a few more pictures.

[image]